# How do you access columns with a space in them via mysql_fetch_object?

Tags: php

When using `mysql_fetch_object()` to return objects from a MySQL query, sometimes column names have spaces in them, and cannot be aliased, such as when running `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`. The procedure definition is returned in a column named `Create Procedure`. In my case, the data abstraction layer only allows the use of `mysql_fetch_object()`, so I can't simply use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to work around this problem.

Can I access columns with spaces in when using `mysql_fetch_object()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took me a while to crack, so I thought I'd post it here, hence the quick answer. :)

```
// Internally, this db abstraction layer uses mysql_fetch_object().
$query = $db->query('SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE `%s`', 'test');
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $procedure = $row->{'Create Procedure'};
}
```

I don't know if this is specific to a PHP version, but it works under PHP 5.3.1 on Windows, at least.

Answer (score 20):

Generally speaking,

```
$recordname->{"my column name"}
```

will do the trick.

You can also do a `print_r($record);` to find out how the columns are represented in the object.

Comment: Worked for me - perfect.

Answer (score -3):

Use quotes. Example: "name with spaces"

Comment: Not a very descriptive answer, this. '$obj = (object) array('name with spaces' => 'testing'); echo $obj->"name with spaces";' doesn't work, you need the curly braces.